# Finding the row with the biggest difference of two columns in excel

Tags: excel, multiple-columns, rows, difference

I have a table with three columns. One for the date, the other min temperature and the other max temperature. I want to find the day that showed the greatest difference between the two temperatures. How do I do that in excel?
This is for instance what i have

```
02/02/2010  30.0   31.0
02/03/2010  29.4   27.2
```

so for instance 02/03/2010 had the greatest variation in temperature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=INDEX(temps[Date],MATCH(MAX(ABS(temps[Temp1]-temps[Temp2])),ABS(temps[Temp1]-temps[Temp2]),0))
```

I used structured references where `temps` is the name of the table, but you can use regular addressing if you prefer.

*In some earlier versions of Excel, you may need to "confirm" this **array-formula** by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar*

Comment: Worked well tahnk you

Answer (score 1):

With Microsoft365:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=@SORTBY(A1:A2,ABS(B1:B2-C1:C2),-1)
```

Comment: Hey, i've tried writing this function in my excel but it says that it is not valid